# Spamhaus issue with IP(s) sbl css

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

I tried to delist our IP(s) listed as SBL SCC from the blacklist database spamhaus but I receive the error message "CSS removal denied" and the IP still listed. I even tried sending an email but the issue is not resolved yet.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS component of the SBL, a dedicated snowshoe spam IP address zone, has a fast automated expiration mechanism. Unlike traditional SBL records, SBL CSS records do not have a manual delisting procedure. CSS records are automatically expired after 3 days. For this automatic expiration to work, it is vital that all spamming is terminated.

I think that this message may have occurred because several people have requested to be removed records. Wait three days.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response, but we have this problem with our IP more than three days and the IP still blocked even it increases the number of the sbl css.

Comment: If I have the same problem and I am sure that I am not spammer (checked in emails, firewalls, spam filter, etc .. ) I will forward this issue to my ISP. They have more tools to resolve the problem.

Comment: If you forward the issue to your ISP there respond you to resolve the issue with spamhaus before request to them

Comment: I think this answer is now out of date, because there is definitely a manual delisting procedure now, which available here: https://www.spamhaus.org/css/removal/form/